# Moving/nudge text down but not and the image

Tags: html, css

Hello Gurus: I am trying something but just don't get the theory...I have one main Div and inside of it are: paragraph text and one image (both of these are nested inside their own Divs) (hopeful I did this correctly!)

For easy visualization.... they are both at the top of the html page and the Image is styled as float: right; the text can be styled but that's where I am hung-up.

----- I want to move the TEXT ONLY from its position; downward from the top of the page like 50px-----

When I styled the text with padding or margin, it takes everything; text and the image, and moves everything down Together....HOW can I leave the image where it is currently, and just move the text downward leaving white space at the top above the text and not the image?

Is this a positioning style? Or am I thinking about this all wrong? Thank you kindly for your help!!

Comment: Without seeing some sample HTML and CSS showing the problem, it's hard to say. [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I just tried Padding-top again and I think this worked.  Do I have the right /correct Style theory behind this technique or can I be doing this more efficiently with better html/styling?? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div><img src="blah" class="img-right" /></div>
    <div><p>some text</p></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.wrapper div p {
    position: absolute //can also be relative, depending on your needs
    top: 50px
}
.img-right {
    float: right
}
```

position can be relative or absolute depending on how you need your page styled.

See also:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Comment: Got it, that works great!   and thanks for helping ...sorry I didn't include html/css examples.

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, please mark this question solved :).